# Back Tick version of this command

Tags: shell-script, command-substitution

```
TAROUTPUT=$(tar cvf /tmp/incremental_backup . tar $(find /etc -type f -mtime -1))
```

Please suggest how can i use backtick for above command

Comment: What do you want to do, how to use it further?

Comment: I just want to know how i can use backticks for the command instead of ()

Comment: @ABHISHEKSHARMA any specific reason for using backtick ?

Comment: No specific reason just wanted to get acquainted with the right syntax.

Comment: @ABHISHEKSHARMA that means you don't want to use `$()` anymore ? you wanna replace whole pattern with backtick ?

Comment: Yes replcae () with backtick

Comment: Have you actually *tried it yourself*? Or do you want someone to type it out for you?

Comment: backticks are the WRONG syntax.  The only good answer here is "Don't do that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following command to replace `$()` with your desired backtick,

```
TAROUTPUT=`tar cvf /tmp/incremental_backup.tar \`find /etc -type f -mtime -1\``
```

I would also recommend you to read [difference between `$(command)` and `command` in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming)

Comment: I'm disappointed that someone would dignify this "question" with an answer... Is that what this site has come to?

Comment: @jasonwryan you are right, but I thought of helping OP

Comment: You aren't helping them, you are indulging them. That isn't good for the OP, nor for the wider community.

Comment: @jasonwryan I extremely apologize for that, I should delete my post then. I will make sure next time this wont affect our community and our users.

Comment: You don't have to apologise: *you* haven't done anything wrong...

Comment: @jasonwryan Actually I should have let OP to try himself, rather than indulging him. but my intention was purely to help him. Anyway I will keep your point in mind. thanks